# How to stop a FLV Movie on a Web FLV Player at the last frame

Tags: streaming, flv, movie

I'm using http://flv-player.net -- When the movie finishes, it comes to the first frame after it finishes, and stops there.  I'd like to stop it at the last frame.

How can I do this if I don't have editing access to the FLA file?

Is there a way to accomplish this with this player, or any other free ones out there?

Please suggest a free (or very low cost if no free ones exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this with javascript with the JS player at http://flv-player.net/players/js/ . the preview example there does stop at the last frame, because its onFinish() event just does an alert(), but doesn't call the stop() method. you could also onFinish() call pause().